# How to check if values in column are NOT null and then output a specific value to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently writing a function in pandas to try to check rows in a column to see if they are not null. If they are not null, I want something to be outputed to a new column and for this case it would be 'Financing'. Basically if a row has a value for loan funded date, I want the phrase Financing to be printed a new column called Payment Type.

```
def typepayment(x):
    if x['Loan Funded Date'] != np.nan:
        x['Payment Type'] = 'Financing'
    return x
df2 = df1.apply(typepayment, axis = 1)
df2
```

The output for the code above still outputs Financing in Payment Type for rows that are null in Loan Funded Date. What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`x['Loan Funded Date'] != np.nan` will be `True` if `x['Loan Funded Date']` is null (NaN is not equal with itself). In this case, `x['Payment Type']` will be set to 'Financing'. As a alternative, you can use

```py
m = df1['Loan Funded Date'].notna()
df1.loc[m, 'Payment Type'] = 'Financing'
# or
df1['Payment Type'] = df1['Payment Type'].mask(m, 'Financing')
```